# How to separate out individual sql statements from Oracle SQL script for execution from java code

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have Oracle DB 11g Enterprise Edition and I want to execute sql script from my java code.
I am reading this sql script from a .sql file and the script contains statements such as `create table`, `create type`, `alter table`, `drop type`, `drop procedure`, `insert into` as well as pl/sql blocks with `begin` and `end` and all such constructs.

My question is, how to separate out individual sql statements for execution from java code? In MS SQL I could simply separate these sql statements by `GO` keyword, whereas in Oracle db there is no such separator. So normally what is used as separator in Oracle db scripts?

---

As an exmple say I have following create trigger block in my sql script along with other sql statements. Here I have semicolons which I can not consider as the SQL Statement terminating charter (PL/SQL block can itself contain multiple semicolon-separated statements). Which means I can not use `;` similar to `GO` (in MS SQL).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SQLVersionHistory_SeqNum_TRG
   BEFORE INSERT 
   ON SQLVersionHistory
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
    :NEW.SequenceNumber := SQLVersionHistory_SeqNum.NEXTVAL;
   END;
```

Comment: I guess Oracle would not mind if you end each statement with semicolon ";".

Comment: Aren't the keywords in Java and Sql totally different ? Regular expressions might help

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1305/what-is-the-difference-between-terminating-an-oracle-sql-statement-with-semicolo  this article might be of interest.

Comment: ";" is similar to go, but don't have same behavior when you're using dynamic sql. so give it a try

Comment: Plese see my update in the question for using `;` . It will not work for me.